# Plot cumulative distribution and PDF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a set of data from `x1` to `x47` and `y1` to `y47`.

```
x1, y1
x2, y2
...
x47,y47
```

Here the `x` represent a length group of wool fibers and `y` is a property of each group.

the problem is that `x1` to `x47` do not have uniform distribution.

I need to plot the cumulative distribution and PDF.

1- Lets assume, the points for cumulative distribution are

```
xc1,yc1
xc2,yc2
...
xc47,yc47
```

How to calculate $xc_i$, $yc_i$ from $x_j$ and $y_j$?

2- Lets assume, the probability density function are

```
xp1,yp1
xp2,yp2
...
xp47,yp47
```

How to calculate $xp_i$, $yp_i$ from $x_j$ and $y_j$?

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, I'm not quite sure what you're
trying to do in the short term (making a plot) or in the long term (what you want to find from your data).

Let's consider data $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ known to be from a continuous population.
If we want to use a graphical method to approximate the population
distribution, the usual plot is a histogram. The data are sorted
into bins (usually of equal length) that span the values of the data.
If you have a lot of data, the histogram (or a smoothed version of it) may suggest the shape of the PDF of the population distribution.
A 'density estimator' is a more sophisticated way to try to represent the population PDF.

As a demonstration, let's sample 500 observations from a gamma
distribution with shape parameter 5 and rate parameter 1. This
distribution takes positive values and is noticeably skewed to the
right. The left panel below shows a histogram of these data (with
tick marks showing individual observations)
and the PDF of the population distribution. The right panel
shows the same histogram together with a density estimator.[image]

Here are some summary statistics for the 500 observations:

```
 summary(x);  sd(x)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.7635  3.5430  4.7480  5.0100  6.1410 14.4000 
  ## 2.075215  # SD
```

An empirical cumulative distribution function of a sample (ECDF) assigns
probability $1/n$ to each of the $n$ observations. The
figure below shows the ECDF along with the CDF of the population distribution $Gamma(5, 1)$.

Perhaps an ECDF is the plot of the data you are asking for. 
In many cases the ECDF of a sample does a better job of representing the population CDF than a histogram does of representing the PDF.

I hope some of this is helpful. If not, perhaps it has provided
a framework and some language to help you explain what you are
trying to do.

[image]

*Note:* The graphs were made using R statistical software. The code is
shown below in case you are familiar with R.

```
 set.seed(1235)  # use this to get same sample; remove for fresh sample
 x = rgamma(500, 5, 1)
 summary(x);  sd(x)
 par(mfrow=c(1,2))  # two panels per plot
   hist(x, prob=T, col="wheat", ylim=c(0,.2), main="Histogram and PDF")
     rug(x)
     curve(dgamma(x, 5, 1), lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
   hist(x, prob=T, col="wheat", ylim=c(0,.2), main="Histogram and Density Est.")
     lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="green4", type="l")
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))  # return to default plotting

 plot.ecdf(x, main="ECDF of 500 Observations from Gamma(5, 1) with CDF")
   curve(pgamma(x,5,1), col="blue", lwd=2, add=T)
   rug(x)
```